# Getting errors trying to upgrade Commerce Kickstart 1.24 to 1.34

Tags: commerce, upgrading

I’m trying to upgrade my install of Drupal Commerce version 7.x-1.24 to 7.x-1.34 but am getting an update failed notice that reads:

Commerce_kickstart-7.x-1.34-core.tar.gz does not contain any .info files.

but when opening that package i see there is indeed an info file, Commerce_Kickstart.info

I’ve been Googling this message to see if other’s are having the same issue but curiously i’m not finding anything.

Is doing this manually an option? if so, do i just replace what is in the profiles folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always did this manually. 
You don't need to replace whole profiles folder. Replace commerce_kickstart folder inside profiles only if you have not hacked or changed any file within. If you have changed any module or theme file. First move the folder to sites/all/modules or sites/all/themes folder, then replace that and run update.php.